# Python exercise, guidance for slicing substrings

Tags: python

Please write a program which asks the user to type in a string. The program then prints out all the substrings which begin with the first character, from the shortest to the longest. Have a look at the example below.

```
Please type in a string: test
t
te
tes
test
```

Obviously my code is not the way it supposed to be:

```
stg = input("Please type in a string: ")

print(stg[0])
print(stg[0:5])
print(stg[0:10])
print(stg[10:50])
print(stg[:])
```

Comment: It isnt obvious, does your code not do what you expect it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
userString = input("Gimme String: ")
# Looping based on the given String
# Last Value is not included so you need to increment the value by one
for i in range(len(userString)):
    # Last Value is not included so you need to increment the value by one
    print(userString[:i+1])

#Alternative
for i in range(1,len(userString)+1):
    print(userString[:i])
```

Comment: Thank you, comments helped massively.
But can i piggyback of this and ask you how to get this result:
`Please type in a string: test
t
st
est
test`

Comment: @User216345 Just change `[:ì]` of the alternative implementation in the slice with `[:i*-1]`

Comment: `Gimme String: test
tes
te
t`

Comment: This is what it returned back,while i need it to print out all the substrings which end with the last character, from the shortest to the longest.
` t
st
est
test`

Answer (score 2):

ok, this is a homework and I don't give you the exact solution... but as some points:

1. you have a string and want to print first 1 letter, first 2 letters and so on... so your range end must increase one by one...
2. you don't know about input length so you can't use hard code and use a loop
3. for `loop` you need to know about string length and use a builtin method for getting the length...

any question? ask it...

Answer (score 0):

```py
stg = input("Please type in a string: ")
print("\n".join([stg[0:i+1] for i in range (len(stg))]))
```

Output:

```
t
te
tes
test
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple `for` loop

```
stg = 'test'
temp_str = ''
for i in range(len(stg)):
    temp_str = temp_str + stg[i]
    print(temp_str)
```

Comment: Ty sanju can you please explain 'stg[i]' this part specifically the i?

Comment: also can ypu loo into this one too 
i need it to print out all the substrings which end with the last character, from the shortest to the longest. 
input test

` t 

st
 est
 test `

Comment: Let's store my name `SANJU` in variable `string`.  Now in order to get the first element of my name, S, you need to use `indexing`. Thus, `string[0]` would give us S and `string[1]` would give us A and so on.  That is what I am doing above. Getting all the string elements from`stg` though indexing. `i` stores the value of 0,1,2,3, which we are getting by applying `range ()` function on the total length of the string.

Comment: @User216345 For second part,  `stg = 'test'
for i in range(1,len(stg)+1):
       print(stg[ -i:])`

Answer (score 0):

```
input_str1 = input("Please type in a string: ")
i = 0
while i < len(input_str1):
    print(input_str1[0:i+1])
    i+=1
```